# Handle exception globally for a data pipeline

Tags: apache-flink

I have data pipeline of 5 different task . if there is any exception in any of the task then move it to error kafka topic. is there any exception handler hook

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Flink's [side output functionality](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/side_output.html) for collecting exceptions and then outputting them to the Kafka topic.

```
final OutputTag<String> outputTag = new OutputTag<String>("side-output"){};
SingleOutputStreamOperator<Integer> task1 = ...;
SingleOutputStreamOperator<Integer> task2 = ...;
SingleOutputStreamOperator<Integer> task3 = ...;
DataStream<String> exceptions1 = task1.getSideOutput(outputTag);
DataStream<String> exceptions2 = task2.getSideOutput(outputTag);
DataStream<String> exceptions3 = task3.getSideOutput(outputTag);

DataStream<String> exceptions = exceptions1.union(exceptions2, exceptions3);
exceptions.addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer(...));
```

#### Update

You can also wrap your result into `Left` and exceptions in `Right` of the `Either` type. At the end of your pipeline you need to split the stream into payload and exceptions via the `split/select` function.

```
DataStream<Either<Payload, Exception>> stage2 = stage1.flatMap(...);
DataStream<Either<Payload2, Exception>> stage3 = stage2.flatMap((Either<Payload, Exception> payload, Collector out) -> {
    if (payload.isLeft()) {
        out.collect(Left.of(map(payload.left)));
    } else {
        out.collect(Right.of(payload.right()));
    }   
});

SplitStream<Either<Payload2, Exception>> split = stage3.split((Either<Payload2, Exception> value) -> {
    if (value.isLeft()) {
        return Colletions.singleton("left");
    } else {
        return Collections.singleton("right");
    }
});

DataStream<Either<Payload2, Exception>> payloads = split.select("left");
DataStream<Either<Payload2, Exception>> exceptions = split.select("right");
```

Comment: Emitting data to a side output is possible from the following functions:

ProcessFunction
CoProcessFunction
ProcessWindowFunction
ProcessAllWindowFunction

Actually have two RichFlatmap function in pipeline and context is not available  to output.

Comment: Then I would output an Either<OriginalType, Exception> and split select further downstream whether it is a Left or Right.

Comment: @TillRohrmann `SplitStream` [seems](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/SplitStream.html) to be _deprecated_. What do you recommend then?

Comment: Instead of using the `SplitStream`, you should now use the side outputs: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/side_output.html